# SSRS 2008 Broken in Chrome

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Note, this is 2008, not 2008 R2.

This isn't an unknown problem, but I can't seem to get it to work. Seems like all of the solutions I've tried relate to 2008 R2 and above versions. Chrome updated and now our reports are showing in a small window instead of a full browser window.

I've searched high and low for a solution for this one. This seems to be the universal solution but it doesn't want to work, even after restarting SSRS:

[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports are blank in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043409)

I'm at a loss on this one. Does 2008 R2 differ that much in terms of reporting services configurations? The easy answer here is to use IE for reports, but our SAAS apps run better on Chrome and link to our reporting services reports.

Other fixes tried:

- Anything from I could find from the Chrome Store: SSRS Fix, IE Tab which works, but we have over 75 machines and buying licensing right now isn't an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who cares,

Our SQL 2008 instance was not on SP3. After installing SP3 everything looks to have taken care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-fix/gklhehemnkbjbccoeneabopaflildkah?hl=en) that fixes a common bug for viewing SSRS reports in Chrome.

I had the same issue and this was a fix for me.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Unfortunately this one isn't working for me.